# IndexOutOfBoundsException with DatagramChannel.receive(buf);

Tags: java, android, datagram

I'm a complete noob when it comes to networking programming.

I'm getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4095): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: length=18, offset=0, buffer size=0
```

At the following line:

```
SocketAddress servaddr = udpChannel.receive(rcvHskBuf);
```

This is how I create the buffer

```
ByteBuffer rcvHskBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(packetSize);
```

For the sake of debugging I changed the argument (which can be changed in the app) from the default `1432` to `1432*20` as explained below.

How do I go about debugging this? I tried changing the `allocateDirect()` argument to 20 times larger than it was before, yet I still get this issue.

Here's the full error log:

```
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: length=18, offset=0, buffer size=0
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.net.DatagramPacket.setLengthOnly(DatagramPacket.java:234)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.net.DatagramPacket.setLength(DatagramPacket.java:222)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.postRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:528)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.receiveDirectImpl(DatagramChannelImpl.java:232)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.receive(DatagramChannelImpl.java:185)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at com.alu.wireless.puredata.PSConnection.UDPInitialization(PSConnection.java:315)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at com.alu.wireless.puredata.PSConnection.PSInitialization(PSConnection.java:73)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at com.alu.wireless.puredata.PureDataActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(PureDataActivity.java:262)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at com.alu.wireless.puredata.PureDataActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(PureDataActivity.java:1)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-27 22:28:01.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2753):     ... 4 more
```

The weird thing is, the app prints the contents of the buffer just fine. Obviously the code that prints the contents of the buffer is situated **after** the line that caused the exception (line 315, written above, where I create the buffer).

Any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show more code? Specifically where you create the buffer.

Comment: Definitely. Editing right now!